# Xfce initialization script

Tags: xfce, profile, session

In an attempt to disable the bell in Xfce, I have created a `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Disable bell
xset b off
```

But now, the system bounces back to the login screen at every login attempt. What should I have used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` is to start the whole XFCE session. Since you aren't starting any program, the session ends as soon as the script exits.

You could mkae that script include the system script. (The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/startxfce4.1.html) says to copy the system script, but don't do that: the system script is likely to change from version to version.) Find out where the system script is; for example it's `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` on Ubuntu. In your `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc`, run your initial customizations, then the system script.

```
#!/bin/sh
xset b off
. /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc
```

Alternatively, add `xset b off` as an [application in the autostart list](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences#application_autostart) (Settings → Session and Startup → Application Autostart → Add).